# Laravel running on docker but cannot connect to localhost

Tags: laravel, docker

I have been using [vessel](https://vessel.shippingdocker.com) for my laravel projects on my Windows pc.
Recently I decided to install it on my macbook.
Did everything to the book, all the initializing as such.

My docker container says everything is running, but when I try to go to the webpage to https://localhost, on safari, I get a completely blank page.

I tried going to chrome and it gives me a "HTTP Error 500" but, it there are no server errors because docker is telling me everything is running.

I checked if anything is blocking me on port 80 but nothing besides docker is running.

What else could I do to debug this?

Comment: A HTTP 500 Error indicates that the web server (Apache?) ran into problems with the PHP code. The web server is running (and working correctly). Check the Laravel logs - here are [the docs for the latest version](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging). My guess is that your database configuration is incorrect and Laravel cannot connect to a database.

Comment: Found the culprit to be faulty php and composer installation. After running composer updates I got everything working!